# Change Windows version numbers?

Tags: windows-registry, compatibility, windows-server-2012, version

When I try to run a certain installer `.exe`, I get:

> Unsupported operating system, major=6, version=2.2, sp=0.0, type=3

My plan is to contact the vendor, *but perhaps there is a quick fix? Is it possible to temporarily change `type=3` to `type=1` by editing the registry?*

The software supports Windows XP through Windows 8. I already tried running in compatibility modes for XP, Vista, and 7, and I get the same error message.

Comment: My gut feeling is that `type=3` specifies a server version of Windows, but I can't find a reference. Windows NT 6.2 is what is usually referred to as [Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8), which matches well the [Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) version you mention that you are trying to run it on. Have you tried installing the software on, say, its client counterpart Windows 8?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's why I'm asking to change to `type=1`. I don't have access to a Windows 8 machine.